# Google App Engine: global name 'X' is not defined

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using inheritance in my code which is running on main.py file on the Google App Engine. In my parent class, I do a bunch of computations and store the results in a bunch of variables. Now, I want to use those variables in my child class, and thus I inherited the parent class in order to access those parent variables.

Parent class

```
class MainPage(Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("indexab.html")
    def post(self):
        vam_id = str(randint(1, 5000)) 
        name = self.request.get("name")
        clas = self.request.get("clas")
        roll_no = int(self.request.get("roll_no"))
        semester = int(self.request.get("semester"))
        q1 = int(self.request.get("1"))
        q2 = int(self.request.get("2"))
        q3 = int(self.request.get("3"))
        q4 = int(self.request.get("4"))
        q5 = int(self.request.get("5"))
        q6 = int(self.request.get("6"))
        q7 = int(self.request.get("7"))
        q8 = int(self.request.get("8"))
        q9 = int(self.request.get("9"))

        total = Survey.all().count()

        q1sea2 = Survey.all().filter("clas = ","SE-A").filter("q1 = ", 12).count()
        q1sea4 = Survey.all().filter("clas = ","SE-A").filter("q1 = ", 14).count()
        q1sea6 = Survey.all().filter("clas = ","SE-A").filter("q1 = ", 16).count()
        q1sea8 = Survey.all().filter("clas = ","SE-A").filter("q1 = ", 18).count()
        q1sea0 = Survey.all().filter("clas = ","SE-A").filter("q1 = ", 10).count()
        q1sea = float((q1sea2*2 + q1sea4*4 + q1sea6*6 + q1sea8*8 + q1sea0*10))/float(total)

#some more code 

self.render("thanx.html")
```

Child class

```
class AdminPage(MainPage):
    def get(self):
        self.render("admin1.html", q1sea = q1sea)
```

However, I get the following error in my log:

```
self.render("admin1.html", q1sea = q1sea)
NameError: global name 'q1sea' is not defined
```

What seems to be wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `self.q1sea = ...` instead of single `q1sea = ...`. Otherwise, the garbage collector will delete the reference when `post()` returns.

Also, you need to call `MainPage.post()` before using `MainPage.q1sea` in your child class.

That's the theory. In practice, as @DanielRoseman said, you wouldn't want to do that, use the database instead to store your data and load it later.

Answer (score 4):

What you're trying to do makes no sense at all. The post and get are on completely different requests. Even if you could persist data between then like that, you wouldn't want to because all other users would also get access to that data.

You need to store the data somewhere between requests - either in the database, or in the session.